# How to send data to ajax using post method

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to generate pdf from table and want to get only that where id='$category'.

getting the category from another page

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$category = $_POST['category'];
echo $category;
}

?>



<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#employee_grid').DataTable({
     "processing": true,
     "sAjaxSource":"response.php",
     'serverMethod': 'post',
     "dom": 'lBfrtip',
     "buttons": [
        {
            extend: 'collection',
            text: 'Export',
            buttons: [
                'copy',
                'excel',
                'csv',
                'pdf',
                'print'
            ]
        }
    ]
    });
});
</script>
```

in this i want to send $category value to ajax (response.php) .
how it possible

Comment: First, you seem to be using quite an old version of DataTables.  I highly suggest that you update to the most recent version.  However, if you decide not to, I believe that what you are looking for is the `fnServerParams` parameter.  You can find more information about it [here](https://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side) (towards the bottom)

Comment: okay,  but how to get those pushed data into the response.php page

Comment: Did you read the linked documentation?  If you click "show details" it gives a very detailed example